# File executable Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux

I have following type of file:
File Type: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
MIME Type: application/x-executable,

with

Permission:  -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 16725 Apr  9 23:08 /var/www/irisreg

Getting the 'Segmentation Fault' error when executing through terminal (./irisreg).

The server is 64-bit Ubuntu LTS 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 32-bit binary that you're trying to run on a 64-bit host.

Did you install the 32-bit shared libraries? I don't have access to a test system at the moment, but I believe the package name is "ia32-libs" or similar.

Comment: That already installed.